# Pandas rolling correlation always returns NaN when there is a NaN. Not the same behavior as DataFrame.corr

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The below code will output only Nan Values

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 3, np.nan, 4,5,6],'A': [0, 1, 2,3, 4,5,6]})
df["corr"] = df['A'].rolling(4).corr(df['B'],min_periods=1)
print(df["corr"] )
```

It seems that min_periods option is not working. I wish I had the same behavior as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 3, np.nan],'A': [0, 1, 2, 3]})
print(df.corr() )
```

That will print the correct correlation even with a NaN value. I can't just filter out NaN rows because I'm working with a timeseries object and that would give me windows with different time periods.

Using latest pandas version (1.4.3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may check with `min_periods` with `rolling`

```
df['cor'] = df['A'].rolling(4,min_periods=1).corr(df['B'])
Out[305]: 
0           NaN
1    1.00000000
2    0.98198051
3    0.98198051
4    0.92857143
5    0.98198051
6    1.00000000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Oh... missed that the min_periods argument is on the rolling call, not on the corr. Thanks!